# VSTO Selecting and Modifying an existing Ordered List

Tags: ms-word, vsto, office-interop

I have an ordered list in my Word document, and I want to add a new element between elements 2 and 3. The easiest way to do this would probably be to get the location of the end of the second element, but I don't know how to do this. Does anyone know how to do this?

All help is greatly appreciated and I always accept an answer!

Comment: Is the new element under the same 'parent'? or is this multilevel e.g. 2.a ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a document consisting of just a simple ListParagraph:

1. List item 1
2. List item 2
3. List item 3

If you want to insert a list item between 2 and 3, you can get the second list paragraph and add a paragraph:

```
    MSWord.Application app = (MSWord.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
  MSWord.Document doc = app.ActiveDocument;

  doc.ListParagraphs[2].Range.Paragraphs.Add();
```

this will insert a new 3rd list paragraph:

1. List item 1
2. List item 2
3. ---->code will add this one
4. List item